# vis.js: Capture edge click event

Tags: jquery, charts, vis.js

I know we can register **`node`** click event in **vis.js** but I want to listen **`edge`** click event. I have gone through [documentation](http://visjs.org/docs/network/edges.html) but could not be any helpful. I was wondering If It Is even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook the following event in your vis.js network configuration to perform any action when an Edge is selected:

```
selectEdge:function(obj){
console.log(obj);
}
```

You can read more about this configuration [here](https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/docs/network/index.html?keywords=selectEdge#Events):

Cheers !

Comment: Thank Umer for being specific to solution.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you can use the same method that you do with nodes. For example:

```
network.on("click"), function(params) {
    if (params.edges.length > 0) {// if some edge is selected
        // do something with the array of edge ids (params.edges)
        // alternatively, you could call network.getSelectedEdges()
        // to obtain the same array of edge ids
    }
}
```

Note that you can do the same with nodes by selecting params.nodes in the above code instead of params.edges.
If this answer helps you out, please mark it as an answer to the question.

Comment: This might work, but this is not the proper way of doing this. Please check my answer for proper implementation

Comment: This might work, but this is not the proper way of doing this. Please check my answer for proper implementation

Comment: I think there's nothing improper with my suggestion above, although I'm glad to see there's yet another way of doing this which seems more elegant (vis.js has likely more functionality since I've used it).